# How is a view positioned if you do not define the top, left, right, or left properties?

Tags: mobile, view

What should be used to view a webpage inside of a mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the mobile platform you are talking about. On iOS, you can use a UIWebView. You will want to subclass it and define any custom behavior.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html